# Dataframe not storing values

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Pack_Perc = [[0]*4]*5
Pack_Dist = pd.DataFrame(Pack_Perc)
for i in range(4):
    Pack_Dist.iloc[0][i] = my_data.iloc[i+1][9]
    Pack_Dist.iloc[1][i] = my_data.iloc[i+1][11]
    Pack_Dist.iloc[2][i] = my_data.iloc[i+1][13]
    Pack_Dist.iloc[3][i] = my_data.iloc[i+1][15]
    Pack_Dist.iloc[4][i] = my_data.iloc[i+1][17]

print(Pack_Dist)
```

I am trying to run above code & when I'm printing "Pack_Dist" instead of printing newly assigned values, system prints all 0s(the old values). Please provide any solution.

Comment: how does it look like your my_data

Answer (score 0):

You should have provided my_data; but the only explanation is that value of those indices in my_data are zero.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).